# OpenProject API docs - Attachment endpoint - how to get this to work OR better understanding of multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, openproject

This is from: https://www.openproject.org/docs/api/endpoints/attachments/

> To add an attachment to a work package, a client needs to issue a
> request of type multipart/form-data with exactly two parts.
>
> The first part must be called metadata. Its content type is expected
> to be application/json, the body must be a single JSON object,
> containing at least the fileName and optionally the attachments
> description.
>
> The second part must be called file, its content type should match the
> mime type of the file. The body must be the raw content of the file.
> Note that a filename must be indicated in the Content-Disposition of
> this part, however it will be ignored. Instead the fileName inside the
> JSON of the metadata part will be used.

I believe I'm understanding a general idea of what is occurring, i.e. how multipart/form data works as an enctype, why it exists, I get that I need to send two parts in the above description. One a JSON Object, and the other a file that also has a content disposition set with a filename parameter...

Beyond this very loose "understanding" I couldn't/wouldn't be able to translate this to a fetch statement or doing something in Postman (when I've tried it's summarily failed).

Could someone point me in the right direction to assist in my endeavor?

(note, I generally use Fetch/javascript for any such activities, if that matters...)

My last, not working, code:

```
const formData = new FormData();
    let uploadFile = articleImages[0].src;
    let jsonPayload = { "metadata": { "fileName": "randomfilename.jpg", "description": "Random Description" }};
    console.log(jsonPayload);
    formData.append( "metdata", jsonPayload );
    formData.append( "file", uploadFile);
    for (const value of formData.values()) {
      console.log(value);
    }
    fetch('https://***/api/v3/work_packages/***/attachments', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('apikey:***'),
        'referrer': '',
        'credentials': 'include',
        'mode':'cors'
      },
      body: formData,
    })
```

This would give the error:

```
{_type: 'Error', errorIdentifier: 'urn:openproject-org:api:v3:errors:PropertyConstraintViolation', message: "File can't be blank.", _embedded: {…}}
errorIdentifier: "urn:openproject-org:api:v3:errors:PropertyConstraintViolation"
message: "File can't be blank."
_embedded: {details: {…}}
_type: "Error"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

### Thank you all.

To answer recent comments:

1. In postman:

   "_type": "Error",
   "errorIdentifier": "urn:openproject-org:api:v3:errors:MultipleErrors",
   "message": "Multiple field constraints have been violated.",
   "_embedded": {
   "errors": [
   {
   "_type": "Error",
   "errorIdentifier": "urn:openproject-org:api:v3:errors:PropertyConstraintViolation",
   "message": "File can't be blank.",
   "_embedded": {
   "details": {
   "attribute": "filename"
   }
   }
   },
   {
   "_type": "Error",
   "errorIdentifier": "urn:openproject-org:api:v3:errors:PropertyConstraintViolation",
   "message": "The content type of the file cannot be blank.",
   "_embedded": {
   "details": {
   "attribute": "contentType"
   }
   }
   }
   ]
   }

See image for what I sent:
[image]

Comment: `let uploadFile = articleImages[0].src;` — Whatever that is, it is unlikely to be a file. It might be a URL, but not a file.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. I do understand why you say that, but it's 100% a file. see output from console.log above.

Comment: I don't see any console log output there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahoi rogelio,

first thing is, that your metadata JSON is nested too much. Value should be `{ "fileName": "randomfilename.jpg", "description": "Random Description" }`, without the `metadata` key on top.

Second, I do not really know, how `fetch` constructs its requests, but this is an example of how the request body should look like:

```
-----------------------------35500998851541290908403510937
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"

{"fileName":"test.txt"}
-----------------------------35500998851541290908403510937
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

This is a test text.

-----------------------------35500998851541290908403510937--
```

In addition, it would be interesting to know, what is in the embedded details of the response error. ;)

Hope I can help!

##### Edit

I built this request in Postman, and it works without flaws. This is how to setup the request: [postman setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG5Ww.png)

Comment: Ahoi! (Ahoj, jak se máš?) - Perfect! I'll be back to my desk very shortly and will try/debug.